# Mind-bogglingly slow disk read performance in KVM guest

Tags: virtualization, disk, io

I'm running Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 with all the latest updates. I've installed KVM and a guest with the same Ubuntu Server version. My problem is that the guest is crazy slow at reading a file. If I run `cat .bashrc`, it takes about *twelve seconds* to read the file to the console. The second time I run the command, it's instant. I notice this slowdown everywhere. Logging in via SSH takes 25 seconds. Opening a file in vim takes 25 seconds. Even `ls -la` sometimes pauses half-way through.

It only happens when reading not when writing, though I suppose it could be caching the write. And I've installed another clean VM using the same methods, and it has the same problem.

Can anyone take a guess what this could be? I'm at a loss to troubleshoot this further.

### Diagnostics

#### Fast write

Write performance is great. The output of `dd if=/dev/zero of=test.file bs=64M count=1 oflag=dsync` varies a bunch, but is roughly:

```
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
67108864 bytes (67 MB, 64 MiB) copied, 0.162529 s, 413 MB/s
```

For reference, the host records about 600 MB/s.

#### VM disk config

The `disk` section output of `virsh edit vm-guest-name` looks like this:

```
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2' discard='unmap'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/one-1.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
```

I tried disabling cache in `<driver>`, but that didn't help.

#### VM creation (2023-10-04)

I create the VM with the following command:

```
sudo virt-install --name=two --os-variant=ubuntu22.04 --vcpu=2 --ram=2048 --disk size=10 --location=/var/lib/libvirt/boot/ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso,kernel=casper/vmlinuz,initrd=casper/initrd --network bridge:br0 --graphics none --extra-args="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200"
```

#### More ram? (2023-10-10)

I upgraded the VM from 2 GB to 8 GB of RAM (the host has 32 GB), but it didn't make any difference at all. `cat .viminfo` (a 10 kB file) still takes 12+ seconds to output to the console.

#### `ls` shouldn't take so long (2023-10-10)

When running `ls -la`, it sometimes pauses after a very short output before it continues. For example:

```
$ ls -la
total 68
drwxr-x--- 6 user user  4096 Oct
```

But if this is blocking on read, why does it already know how to format the output? Could this blocking be actually happening on the console output and not at the read level? How can I check this?

I'm a bit suspicious, because the VM was created with the `--graphics none --extra-args="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200"` options, and I can imagine something wonky is happening there.

Comment: I had similar bad performance in VirtualBox if I didn't tick the box to "Use Host I/O Cache" (it was not ticked on the hard drive by default). Is there something like that in KVM?

Comment: How much memory on host and given to VM?  Any other info on the VM setup like -smp cores=4,threads=2, -cpu host, etc.

Comment: @ubfan1 I added a note to my answer about how I create the VM. The host has 32 GB and a NVMe SSD (250 GB).

Comment: @OrganicMarble I tried a whole host of changes to the disk definition, but nothing has helped. There are so many possibilities that I could have missed the one that worked, but I can't imagine why this configuration shouldn't work with the default settings. I'm not doing anything special (like SCSI or other special hardware).